# Documentation error for Sort.Orientation?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing some code in VBScript to sort a table in an excel file. My process in this case is to first record a macro doing the sorting manually, and then translate that VBA into VBScript.

The specific part of the code I was working on was

```
With sheet.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add sheet.Range("Table1[Subset]")
    .SortFields.Add sheet.Range("Table1[Domain]")
    .SortFields.Add sheet.Range("Table1[Entity]")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom '<--- this value was generated by the macro recording
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Because VBScript doesn't know the excel VBA enumerations, I have to declare them myself.

So I went to the Microsoft documentation about the [Sort.Orientation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort.orientation) where it says the type of this property is the enumeration [XlSortOrientation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlsortorientation)

This enumeration contains two values:

> Specifies the sort orientation.
>
> | Name | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | xlSortColumns | 1 | Sorts by column. |
> | xlSortRows | 2 | Sorts by row. This is the default value. |

To my surprise there is `xlTopToBottom` value present in that enumeration.
Furthermore not only the macro recorder uses `xlTopToBottom`, but so does the example code in the [documentation for the Sort object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sort)

The value `xlTopToBottom` can be found in the [Constants enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.constants?view=excel-pia)

So my question is:
Why is Microsoft using the value `xlTopToBottom` in both recorded macro's as the API documentation for the `Sort.Orientation` while the only valid values are `xlSortColumns` or `xlSortRows`?

Comment: The simplest way for what you try doing is to use (in VBA ): `Debug.Print xlTopToBottom` It will return 1. So you can use it as it is: `.Orientation = 1`, or declare a constant: `Const xlTopToBottom = 1` and use it in the code as you try now...

Comment: Microsoft uses the same **numeric** constant in many places. Its literal representation is used only **to give to the constant much more sense when you use it for a specific purpose**. Why using more numeric values if not necessary? VBA recognize them in all existing cases.

Comment: @FaneDuru Your first comment does not seem to be related to the question, as this is not what the OP is asking about, and as for your second comment, it would appear that you are arguing that e.g. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (equals 5) should be used in all places where the value 5 is required, to not create additional unrelated constants that also equal to 5, i.e. `PrintOut Copies:=ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`?

Comment: @GSerg On contrarious... I (at least) tried saying that Microsoft uses the same numeric constant/value in many  places, but "Its literal representation (xlTopToBottom) is used only **to give to the constant much more sense when you use it for a specific purpose**". And, if you like confusing people reading your code, you can do what you suggested I meant. VBA does not care about the constant name (literal part)... I asked "Why using **more numeric values** if not necessary?" Microsoft uses more constants with the same value.

Comment: @FaneDuru When designing an enum from scratch, you are likely to start with 0 or 1. Thus, many enums of yours will happen to have the same values, under different names. That will not be *giving more sense to the value 1*, the specific value of 1 is a coincidence, not the reason. The enums are supposed to be opaque. You are supposed to be able to use them without knowing what numeric value a certain enum member happens to have. It is therefore wrong to use a member from an unrelated enum on the basis that it happens to have the same numeric value as a member of another enum.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Can totally be an error in the macro recorder, an error in the documentation, or both. You can probably leave feedback on the page, or raise an issue [on Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/blob/main/api/Excel.Sort.md).

Comment: @GSerg My English is not my best skill, but where did I suggest  "to use a member from an unrelated enum on the basis that it happens to have the same numeric value"? And, if Microsoft does  not want *giving more sense to the constant*, why doesn't it name them `constant1`, `constant2` and so on? Isn't it more relevant to name it `xlTopToBottom`? If not giving more sense to the constant was the reason of naming them in that way, what do you think was the one, please?

Comment: @FaneDuru I'm not asking what the value of `xlTopToBottom` is. I can find that just fine myself. I'm asking why Microsoft is using the wrong enum value in both the generated macro's as the official documentation.

Comment: @FaneDuru `where did I suggest to use "to use a member from an unrelated enum on the basis that it happens to have the same numeric value"` - here: *Microsoft uses the same **numeric** constant in many places. ... Why using more numeric values if not necessary? VBA recognize them in all existing cases.*.

Comment: @GSerg I wanted suggesting that "Numeric values" is different than "Constant names". And why not using 1 value twenty times if they can alocate it to 20 more eloquent named constants? **VBA recognize them in all existing cases** does only mean that they use the same numeric value, not recommending to use constants which does not mean anything for the programmer, the one reading the code...

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the Range.Sort document description of Orientation is incorrect. It says "Set xlSortRows value to 2 to sort by row (this is the default value)." However, xlSortRows = xlLeftToRight = 2 means to sort a row left-right; this is NOT the default. xlSortColumns = xlTopToBottom = 1 means to sort a column up-down; THIS is the default.